# ido-switch-buffer can't be bound to <backtab> in python mode of emacs24

Tags: python, emacs, key-bindings, ido

When I was using emacs23, I configured ido as below:

```
(require 'ido)
(ido-mode t)
(global-set-key (quote [backtab]) (quote ido-switch-buffer))
(define-key ido-common-completion-map (quote [backtab]) 'ido-next-match)
(define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<C-S-iso-lefttab>") 'ido-prev-match)
```

But when I upgrade to emacs24, I found that the backtab in .py is bound to python-indent-dedent-line, so ido-switch-buffer can't be executed.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it in the `python-mode-map` since it takes priority over the global map in python buffers.  And, similarly, minor mode maps would take higher priority than both.

```
(define-key python-mode-map (kbd "<backtab>") 'ido-switch-buffer)
```

Comment: or just set that binding to nil in python-mode-map so that the global map is not overshadowed, At least then, if you change global bindings, you won't need to remember where you have also created bindings in local maps.